# Google Search results not showing up

Tags: javascript, google-search

I have added a custom Google Search to a site and while the search box functions the results page is pathetically empty.

Here is the search box code:

```
<form action="http://www.nu-living.com/info/search_results" id="cse-search-box">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="cx" value="017425724926122041548:jqyv4auvnls" />
<input type="hidden" name="cof" value="FORID:9" />
<input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8" />
<input type="text" name="q" size="31" />
<input type="submit" class="submit" name="sa" value="Search" />
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/cse/brand?form=cse-search-box&amp;lang=en"></script>
```

Here is the display code:

```
<div id="cse-search-results"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var googleSearchIframeName = "cse-search-results";
var googleSearchFormName = "cse-search-box";
var googleSearchFrameWidth = 900;
var googleSearchDomain = "www.google.com";
var googleSearchPath = "/cse";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/afsonline/show_afs_search.js"></script>
```

The site: http://www.nu-living.com

The search results page: http://www.nu-living.com/info/search_results

I have done this on several other sites with success, but this one is just not cooperating. I would appreciate any assistance in getting this to work correctly

Answer (score 1):

<s>Two</s> Three things you need to look at (one related, <s>one</s> two unrelated) from the FireFox error console

> (javascript) Error: uncaught
>   exception: Syntax error, unrecognized
>   expression:

Unrelated but still worth correcting:

> Warning: Unexpected end of file while
>   searching for selector. Source File:
>   http://www.nu-living.com/ Line: 0

... and:

> (parsing) Error: The stylesheet
>   http://www.nu-living.com/css/about.css
>   was not loaded because its MIME type,
>   "text/html", is not "text/css". Source
>   File:
>   http://www.nu-living.com/info/search_results/?cx=017425724926122041548%253Avgp5w3d356w&cof=FORID%253A9&ie=UTF-8&q=testing&sa=Search&siteurl=www.nu-living.com%252F Line: 0

Also, is there a good reason you are including jQuery and related Javascript file references in the body of your HTML document?

**Update:** A problem on your homepage here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#breaking-news ul').newsticker();
  $('#slideshow').cycle();
</script>
```

You should wrap all jQuery calls in `$(document).ready(function() { /* code */ });` to ensure the DOM is ready before you change things - otherwise you'll hit a Javascript error which may prevent other scripts from running if jQuery hasn't had a chance to initialize the `$` variable.

I would wager that this is what is happening with Google Custom Search - a problem with one of your other scripts is breaking script execution before the search script can run.

You should debug your site to correct these problems - [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/javascript) may help with this task.